# Casting all elements of an Array in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, casting, google-bigquery

My input is a string containing an unknowm number of elements: "1,2,3".
From that, I'd like to get an array of integers.

Using SPLIT will get me an array of strings. How to convert this to an array of integers.

My best guess is a user-defined function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT '1,2,3,4,5' str UNION ALL
  SELECT '12,34,56,78'
)
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT CAST(num AS INT64) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(str)) num) arr
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`
```

Comment: I tried to apply this and got error 'Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field num'.

Comment: that's right - array cannot have a null element, so you should add `WHERE NOT num IS NULL` inside ARRAY function!